# Is there any container exists which support IsEnabled property and can have radiobuttons as children

Tags: c#, silverlight, radio-button, silverlight-5.0, isenabled

I am working in **silverlight**  programatically using c# and i have a situation that i want to know if there is any container in silverlight which contains IsEnabled property and can have radiobuttons on it.

I couldn't find any yet. I need both these things it must be able to have radiobutton on it(just like as stackpanel can have on it) and IsEnabled property as well.

Comment: So why you don't use StackPanell?

Comment: StackPanell dont support IsEnabled proprty .

Comment: Any conatiner supporting IsEnabled property and can have Radiobuttons as children can is accepted. Do you know any ?

Comment: No, but you can use Visibility property for change enable status.

Comment: but i want slightly visible GUI. Not all disappered.

Comment: May be that article will help you, but I don't belive that it is a good approach http://msarangam.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/how-to-isenable-property-for-stackpanel-in-silverlight/

Comment: Try using `StackPanel` with `IsHitTestVisible` set to `false`...

Comment: sp.IsHitTestVisible = false; it do nothing.

Comment: @MikkaRin From the given link i tried to do  Stackpanel.Getvisualchildren() method but it dont work because Getvisualchildren is also not supported.

Comment: @MikkaRin thanks for the help . I achieved it using contentcontrol. Please see below.

Answer (score 1):

I used ConentControl to do so and achieved it like this:

Suppose  `StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();` i assume that sp contains UIElements which are to be disabled. and  `ContentControl cc = new ContentControl();` is my content control.

```
cc.Content = sp; cc.IsEnabled=false;
```

worked for me.